# Handling http error 407(Proxy Authentication Required) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-407

In the following javascript, I would like to handle errors based on http error code. It is possible to handle all other types of http errors but not 407, when server sends the status as 407, jqXHR.status shows as "0" not "407". Any idea why it not shows status as 407? Is there any alternate approach to handle 407 errors in client side.

```js
function handleError(jqXHR) {
  if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
      // Server side error
  } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
      // Not found
  } else if (jqXHR.status === 407) {
      // Proxy Authentication is required
      // This is not working, when server send http status code as 407, client side it is recieved as 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test jqXHR.readyState and handle the 'UNSENT' state. (see here: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#xmlhttprequest ) So instead of handling the 'Authentication Required' status, you could handle the 'UNSENT' state instead.

Comment: I think unsent is same as "0" which may occur when there is no internet connectivity?

Comment: "UNSENT"  status caused due so many reasons like no network connection,  fire wall issue, Illegal cross origin request , etc...

Comment: Yeah, and you could authenticate to the proxy, and retry the request a couple of times for all those cases.